# Trouble with assigning one object to class in C#

Tags: c#

I  have two class like below:

```
public class BookTitles
{
    public int BookCode { get; set; }
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    public string BookCategory { get; set; }
}

public class TextBook
{
    public int TCode { get; set; }
    public string TTitle { get; set; }
}
```

I used them like below and I want to assign one class object to another class. but I got Error.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BookTitles book = new BookTitles()
    {
        BookCode = 1,
        BookTitle = "TitleBook1",
        BookCategory = "Story"
    };

    TextBook noteBook = new TextBook();
    noteBook = (TextBook)book;
    noteBook = book as TextBook;
}
```

Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project Project Rank    File    Line    Column  Category    Source  Suppression State   Tool
Error   CS0030  Cannot convert type 'BookTitles' to 'TextBook'  WindowsFormsApplication1    1   C:\Users\**************\Form1.cs    30  24  Compiler    IntelliSense    Active  Compiler

Severity    Code    Description Project Project Rank    File    Line    Column  Category    Source  Suppression State   Tool
Error   CS0039  Cannot convert type 'BookTitles' to 'TextBook' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion WindowsFormsApplication1    1   C:\Users\**************\Form1.cs    31  24  Compiler    IntelliSense    Active  Compiler
```

Comment: Did you intend for `BookTitles` to be a subclass of `TextBook`?

Comment: No @Peter Moore

Comment: Then that's your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast between two different objects that do not have any relation.

In your case I would advise to:

```
noteBook = new TextBook { TCode = book.BookCode, TTitle = book.BookTitle };
```

Another option would be to use inheritance in case that the TextBook has a meaning of parent to BookTitles.

You can do it this way:

```
public class BookTitles : TextBook
{
    public string BookCategory { get; set; }
}

public class TextBook
{
    public int TCode { get; set; }
    public string TTitle { get; set; }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var book = new BookTitles()
    {
        TCode = 1,
        TTitle = "TitleBook1",
        BookCategory = "Story"
    };

    var noteBook = (TextBook)book;
}
```

Comment: They do have a relation, just not one that allows for direct assignment.

Comment: In the real world, book titles aren't a specialization of books (superclass), they are a component of them.

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment is like assigning an engine to a car. They are different things, so one cannot be assigned to the other. Note, though, there is a relationship between an engine and a car, or a BookTitles and a TextBook. Each are a component of the other. I suggest reorganizing your object model like this:

```
public class BookTitles // Suggest you use singular BookTitle
{
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    public string BookCategory { get; set; }
}

public class TextBook
{
    public int TCode { get; set; }
    public BookTitles Title { get; set; }
}
```

You could then do something like:

```
TextBook book = new TextBook
{
    BookCode = 1,
    Title = new BookTitles
    {
        BookTitle = "TitleBook1",
        BookCategory = "Story"
    }
};
```

Comment: Hm. Now the book code is redundant, isn't it? Also, why is `BookTitles` a plural? Was it meant to be a collection?

Comment: Yep book code is redundant, thanks for the catch. As for BookTitles, I kept the OP's name to minimize change from the original code but agree, it should be singluar.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misunderstanding about how objects, relations and inheritance works.

While I'm not completely sure what you're trying to accomplish - I see 4 distinct solutions to the problem.

1. General/Special class-paradigm
2. Implementing Explicit/Implicit casting
3. Relationship by Aggregation/Composition
4. Interface

While the first 3 has already been addressed and answered - the fourth - by interfaces could also be a solution.

```
public interface ITitle
{
     public int BookCode { get; set; }
     public string BookTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Since Interfaces creates a contract for objects to strictly follow - then by casting the two objects to ITitle will assure that the Properties will be set on the object to be assigned to  -

```
public class Booktitles : ITitle
{
    public int BookCode { get; set; }
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    public string BookCategory { get; set; }
}

public class TextBook : ITitle
{
    public int BookCode { get; set; }
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BookTitles book = new BookTitles
    {
        BookCode = 1,
        BookTitle = "TitleBook1",
        BookCategory = "Story"             
    };

    TextBook noteBook = new TextBook();
    (ITitle)notebook = (book as ITitle);
}
```

A thing too notice is that now *TextBook* doesn't have *TCode* & *TTitle* - since the interface that both class' inherits from dictates that the naming for both properties on both classes stays the same - which is also why we can now assign the two properties from one ITitle object to another.

While the use of interfaces is depended on your direct needs - the good thing here is that both classes stays completely decoupled from each-other - while still being able to "share" common properties.

Another thing to note - is that in the code you've shared you've tried using both explicit casting and casting to object with the *as*-keyword - I'm using both just to address that generally there is no difference between them.
Seen from the perspective they both (try to) cast the objects into *ITitle*.

The main difference is how error in casting the object to *ITitle* is done at run time. Casting explicit will throw an error, if the object is not able to be cast too the given type - while with the use of the the *as*-keyword, the casting will be tried and if it should fail - the program would run the next line in the code instead.